# Getting a confusing error whenever I try to run a certain method

Tags: java

So I'm working on a card matching game, and the following method is giving me a lot of trouble.

```
int[] cardmatch = new int[]{};
ArrayList<JButton> card = new ArrayList();

private void cardreset() {
    for(int x = 1; x<=20; x++) {
        if (cardmatch[x] == 0) {
            card.get(x).setIcon(back);
        }
    }
}
```

cardmatch is an array that is normally equal to 0 for all values, but is set to 1 for any cards that are flipped and end up being a match. card is an arraylist containing all of the JButton variables that I'm using as "cards". Both arrays are filled by other methods (I checked, they work fine). This method is supposed to check whether or not the cards have been matched, and flip over any cards that weren't matched, but whenever I try to run it I end up with an error. Any suggestions? The full code is [here.](http://hastebin.com/xocadobuvo.avrasm)

Comment: No your assumption is wrong `cardmatch` is just an empty array. `cardmatch.length` will give you the all truth. If you want an array with twenty 0, just do `int[] cardmatch = new int[20];`. Also indexes start from 0 to `length-1`.

Comment: Please post errors instead of calling them confusing and leaving it at that.

Answer (score 0):

you wrong. you initialize array with empty. so do like this..

```
int MAX = 25;
int[] cardmatch = new int[MAX];
ArrayList<JButton> card = new ArrayList();

private void cardreset() {
    for(int x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        if (cardmatch[x] == 0) {
            card.get(x).setIcon(back);
        }
    }
}
```